# Parsing numbers in natural language (spelled out) in french

Tags: java, parsing, numbers, french

What's the easiest way in Java for parsing a string to extract numbers written in natural language? For example, I'd like to extract the number in `I have thirty three apples`. The number should be low (less than fifty) and will be in french (so `dix sept` for example).

Is there already in the JDK or another lib an enum like [the month one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) or something similar to do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FrenchTranslator {
private static final String EMPTY_SPACE = " ";
private static final Map<String, Integer> frenchNumbers = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("un", 1);
    put("deux", 2);
    put("trois", 3);
    put("quatre", 4);
    put("cinq", 5);
}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String frenchSentence = "J'ai cinq tomates.";
    System.out.println("INPUT: " + frenchSentence);
    List <String> words = extractWordsFromFrenchSentence(frenchSentence);
    String translatedSentence = createTranslatedSentence(words);
    System.out.println("OUTPUT:" + translatedSentence);
}

private static List <String> extractWordsFromFrenchSentence(String frenchSentence){
    return Arrays.asList(StringUtils.splitString(frenchSentence, EMPTY_SPACE));
}

private static String createTranslatedSentence( List <String> words){
   StringBuilder translatedSentence = new StringBuilder();
   words.forEach(word -> {
       if(frenchNumbers.containsKey(word)){
           translatedSentence.append(EMPTY_SPACE + frenchNumbers.get(word));
       }
       else {
           translatedSentence.append(EMPTY_SPACE + word);
       }
   });
   return translatedSentence.toString();
}
}
```

How the algorithm works:

INPUT: J'ai cinq tomates.

OUTPUT: J'ai 5 tomates

From what I understood, you want to detect a written number in a french sentence.

I don't know your precise requirements but in order to help you I have written an algorithm which translates written French numbers (from 1-5) into natural numbers and then recreates the original sentence.

Comment: I was wondering if it exists a class in the JDK or elsewhere (a library?) which could do that and avoid me to initialize a Map of many strings (for example, [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) is an already existing enum with the months (but in english). 
Moreover, you example is based on space, so the number "dix sept" for example wouldn't work (that's why I put thirty three as an example in the english sentence).

Comment: For months it's possible if you use Locale classes. https://memorynotfound.com/java-get-list-month-names-locale/     but I'm not aware of libraries that stock French numbers.